# JQuery | change the innert html content of ul->li->a

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
    <ul class="links main-menu">
    <li class="menu-385 active-trail first active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/">HOME</a></li>
    <li class="menu-386 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/">FIND LOCAL PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li class="menu-387 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/">DO BUSINESS LOCALLY</a></li>
    <li class="menu-388 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/">LOCAL NEWS &amp; EVENTS</a></li>
    <li class="menu-389 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/">BLOG</a></li>
    <li class="menu-390 last active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/">ABOUT US</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I am new to jquery. What I want is i want to wrap inner html of anchor tag(e.g. Home etc) in in a span. I want this functionality through jquery on document ready.

Comment: This looks like Wordpress to me, it would be easier to just edit the menu-function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) to get everything (textNodes and child elements) then wrap them all with [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

```
$(function(){
    $('.main-menu a')   //your target
        .contents()           //get target contents (elements and textNodes)
        .wrapAll('<span>');   //wrap them all with a span

});
```

If you want to wrap each text nodes and elements inside `<a>` with span, let's modify the code a bit, now using [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/):

```
$(function(){
    $('.main-menu a')   //your target
        .contents()           //get target contents (elements and textNodes)
        .wrap('<span>');      //wrap each with span
});
```

jQuery is pretty verbose in their method names, you can search what you want to do, and they have an equivalent method for it.

Comment: Joseph thank for the response. I have tried this but output is like <ul class="links main-menu"><li class="menu-385 active-trail first active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/"><span>HOMEFIND LOCAL PRODUCTSDO BUSINESS LOCALLYLOCAL NEWS &amp; EVENTSBLOGABOUT US</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-386 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/"></a></li>
<li class="menu-387 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/"></a></li>
<li class="menu-388 active"><a class="active" title="" href="/caribootrunk/"></a></li>
<li class="menu-389 active">...

Comment: @F.Calderan [i updated it](http://jsfiddle.net/PrUPj/1/). I missed the part where I used 2 classes. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Use [wrapInner()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.links a').wrapInner('<span />');   
    /** 
     * wrapInner: Wrap an HTML structure around the content of 
     * each element in the set of matched elements.
     */
});
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qPME/

Answer (score 1):

JSFiddle working example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykzQp/1/)

This is the proper way to do it:

```
​​$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.links a").wrapInner('<span>');   
});
```

It transforms

```
<li><a>BLOG</a></li>
<li><a>DO BUSINESS LOCALLY</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a><span>BLOG</span></a></li>
<li><a><span>DO BUSINESS LOCALLY</span></a></li>
```

JSFiddle working example: [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ykzQp/1/)